# Python Programming error

Tags: python, keyerror

Below is my code.

```
print("Preprocessing data...")
with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:

    results = manager.dict()

    preprocess_training = Process(target=preprocess, args=(
        results, "data\\train.csv", False, "train", min_occurrences, train_data_file_name,))

    preprocess_testing = Process(target=preprocess, args=(
        results, "data\\test.csv", True, "test", min_occurrences, test_data_file_name,))

    preprocess_training.start()
    preprocess_testing.start()
    print("Multiple processes started...")

    preprocess_testing.join()
    print("Preprocessed testing data...")

    preprocess_training.join()
    print("Preprocessed training data...")

    training_data = results["train"]
    testing_data = results["test"]

    print("Data preprocessed & cached...")
```

I am getting following error

> File "C:\Users\Samad\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py",
>   line 772, in _callmethod
>       raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
>
> KeyError: 'train'

How it can be resolves?

Comment: You don't have a `train` key in your `results` dictionary.

Comment: look at output of `results.keys()` and see if there is `"train"` key

Comment: Showing these empty []; what i can do further?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the exception in case it's not set in the dict :

```
try:
    training_data = results["train"]
    testing_data = results["test"]
except KeyError as ex:
    print("Missing key in dictionary : {}".format(ex))
```

It's more pythonic to ask for forgiveness than permission.